# Merging .tif files downloaded from Google Earth Engine in correct order in Python

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, merge, gdal-merge

When you download a large image from Google Earth Engine, it is in multiple small images. Each sub-image name contains the x_min and y_min coordinates of that image.
[image]

It is described here - https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_upload#tfrecord

How to join all these .tif files into one .tif file in right order by using a Python script.

Comment: take a look at this, you can merge the tiffs like this, if you are merging a complete set I don't think the order would be an issue. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56985/merging-many-rasters-using-python

Answer (score 6):

Merging tiles can be accomplished using:

1. GDAL's [gdal_merge](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html). An example is given in [calling gdal_merge into python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/calling-gdal-merge-into-python-script)
2. Rasterio's [rasterio.merge](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.merge.html). An example is given in [Rasterio: tool for creating mosaic?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247231/)

It is not necessary to order the tiles in a specific way... they are non-overlapping.

Comment: Are these tiles connected automatically in the right order? I mean if the correct order of tiles in 1-2-3-4 horizontally, I hope they will not be connected in some random fashion. All tiles are non-overlapping but adjoining (cab be vertical or horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the tif files by coordinate pair this will do it.

```
from osgeo import gdal
tiffiles=["basefilename-99-100.tif","basefilename-98.7-200.tif","basefilename-101-300.tif","basefilename-100.25-400.tif","basefilename-99.925-500.tif","basefilename-97.552-100.tif"]
coordarray=[]
tifdict={}
for tf in tiffiles:
    ds = gdal.Open(tf)
    w = ds.RasterXSize
    h = ds.RasterYSize
    gtrans = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    minx = gtrans[0]
    miny = gtrans[3] + w*gtrans[4] + h*gtrans[5] 
    # splittifname=tf.split("-")
    coords=(minx,miny)
    coordarray.append(coords)
    tifdict[coords]=tf
coordarray=sorted(coordarray,key=lambda k:(k[0],k[1]))
for coord in coordarray:
    ### DO STUFF TO COMBINE THE RASTER TO A STACK
    print(tifdict[coord])
```

I don't think I explain myself clearly, this will put your tif in order by coordinate from min x min y of the set, then you can merge or place the file names in order on .txt file and batch process. I change the code to use the coord value in the tif file instead of value in file  name but  I have  not had a chance to test you may need to declare the spatial reference somewhere.

Comment: I want to combine tiff files to make one big tif file. They should be combined at their right places as per coordinates, not just random place.